# ASCollectionNode showsVerticalScrollIndicator is dot work

Tags: ios, objective-c, textures, asyncdisplaykit

I use [AsyncDisplayKit](https://github.com/facebookarchive/AsyncDisplayKit) ASCollectionView, but it's not showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO, can't work?  Who can tell me ， thanks

```
 self.collectionNode = [[ASCollectionNode alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
    self.collectionNode.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionNode.delegate = self;
    self.collectionNode.view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    // this can't working
```

Debug:

```
2018-03-12 10:04:37.255867+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17126525] [Node] View controller <LTProcessViewController: 0x7f99e365ff90> will appear
2018-03-12 10:04:37.270323+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17126525] [Collection] performBatchUpdates <ASTableNode: 0x7f99e3681410> {  }
2018-03-12 10:04:37.270649+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17126525] [Collection] <ASTableView: 0x7f99e4083c00> Skipped update because load hasn't happened.
2018-03-12 10:04:37.272763+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17126525] [Collection] Initial reloadData <ASTableNode: 0x7f99e3681410>
2018-03-12 10:04:37.282165+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17126525] [Collection] New content: { itemCounts = [ <S0: 40> ] }
2018-03-12 10:04:37.296018+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17126665] *** Assertion failure in -[ASCollectionNode view], /Users/vvv/Desktop/liveTeach/vvv-iphone/Pods/Texture/Source/ASDisplayNode.mm:679
2018-03-12 10:04:37.296049+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17126681] *** Assertion failure in -[ASCollectionNode view], /Users/xxx/Desktop/liveTeach/xxx-iphone/Pods/Texture/Source/ASDisplayNode.mm:679
2018-03-12 10:04:37.296076+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17127565] *** Assertion failure in -[ASCollectionNode view], /Users/xxx/Desktop/liveTeach/xxx-iphone/Pods/Texture/Source/ASDisplayNode.mm:679
2018-03-12 10:04:37.296095+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17126669] *** Assertion failure in -[ASCollectionNode view], /Users/xxx/Desktop/liveTeach/xxx-iphone/Pods/Texture/Source/ASDisplayNode.mm:679
2018-03-12 10:04:37.296113+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17126680] *** Assertion failure in -[ASCollectionNode view], /Users/xxx/Desktop/liveTeach/xxx-iphone/Pods/Texture/Source/ASDisplayNode.mm:679
2018-03-12 10:04:37.296131+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17127564] *** Assertion failure in -[ASCollectionNode view], /Users/xxx/Desktop/liveTeach/xxx-iphone/Pods/Texture/Source/ASDisplayNode.mm:679
2018-03-12 10:04:37.296153+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17127563] *** Assertion failure in -[ASCollectionNode view], /Users/xxx/Desktop/liveTeach/xxx-iphone/Pods/Texture/Source/ASDisplayNode.mm:679
2018-03-12 10:04:37.296174+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17127562] *** Assertion failure in -[ASCollectionNode view], /Users/xxx/Desktop/liveTeach/xxx-iphone/Pods/Texture/Source/ASDisplayNode.mm:679
2018-03-12 10:04:37.305469+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17126525] [Node] Propagating new traits for <LTProcessViewController: 0x7f99e365ff90>: { userInterfaceIdiom = Phone; containerSize = {414, 687}; horizontalSizeClass = Compact; verticalSizeClass = Regular; forceTouchCapability = Available }
2018-03-12 10:04:37.305984+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17126525] [Node] Propagating new traits for <LTProcessViewController: 0x7f99e365ff90>: { userInterfaceIdiom = Phone; containerSize = {414, 687}; horizontalSizeClass = Compact; verticalSizeClass = Regular; forceTouchCapability = Available }
2018-03-12 10:04:37.353424+0800 LiveTeach-iPhone[29773:17127563] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This method must be called on the main thread'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a7e112b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f1e5f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a7e62f2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
3   Foundation                          0x000000010b637d69 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
4   LiveTeach-iPhone                    0x000000010931bb51 -[ASDisplayNode view] + 1009
5   LiveTeach-iPhone                    0x000000010929ba56 -[ASCollectionNode view] + 54
6   LiveTeach-iPhone                    0x00000001090c14c6 -[LTProcessCellView initWithModel:] + 2758
7   LiveTeach-iPhone                    0x00000001090a9807 __64-[LTProcessViewController tableNode:nodeBlockForRowAtIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 71
8   LiveTeach-iPhone                    0x0000000109414748 __51-[ASTableView dataController:nodeBlockAtIndexPath:]_block_invoke_2 + 104
9   LiveTeach-iPhone                    0x000000010928599f -[ASCollectionElement node] + 127
10  LiveTeach-iPhone                    0x00000001092d360a __58-[ASDataController _allocateNodesFromElements:completion:]_block_invoke + 154
11  LiveTeach-iPhone                    0x00000001092e55ad __ASDispatchApply_block_invoke + 93
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110ea12f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110ea233d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110ea7406 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1895
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110eae102 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 772
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110eadda0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011136d1ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011136cc4d start_wqthread + 13
)
```

this is debug message, But I can't fix it。 who can help me , thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

ASDisplayNode is Async class, you can't just call view property directly, you must wait when it will be loaded. And ASDisplayNode's have a method for overwrite it by subclass `-(void)didLoad;' or block for load logic directly in Node (as in your case):

```
[self.collectionNode onDidLoad:^(__kindof ASCollectionNode *node) {
  node.view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
}];
```

And didLoad must be called on MainThread, not remember but i think didLoad called on Main by default, need check it.